# Upgrade application to Grails 2.1.1

Tags: grails

i have upgraded a grails application using `grails upgrade` command. But the problem is when i try to run the application using `grails run-app`, it shows unresolved dependency error as mentioned: | Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.
roovy for more information):

- org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.core:3.0.2.RELEASE
- org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:3.0.2.RELEASE

What should i do to resolved dependencies and run the application. I tried to clean app using `grails clean` and also tried to install the dependencies with no success.

Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you will need to upgrade your application's `spring-security-core` plugin dependency to a more recent version.  There are two different sets of Spring-related JARs in different Maven repositories under different artifact IDs.  The ones in Maven central are called `spring-*` and the ones in the [SpringSource EBR](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/) are called `org.springframework.*`.  Older versions of the `spring-security-core` Grails plugin depended on the EBR artifacts, newer versions use the ones in Maven Central.